# How to efficiently copy MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, import, export, database-backups, dbmigrate

Is there any other way to copy MySQL databases from one computer to the other, except importing each and every database individually?

Actually in my office PC there seems to have a problem, so they are changing all the PC's in the office. My MySQL has a lot of databases in it. So I am looking for a one shot process so that all the databases gets copied to my new PC.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [`mysqldump`](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysqldump).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can simply backup the whole database and restore it on the other PC. Find below the steps;

**Backing Up Your Database**

1. First, navigate to your phpMyAdmin page via cPanel or whatever alternative administration system your host provides i.e. Plesk etc. and log in
2. From the dropdown box on the left (or the text link) click on your e107 database to show all the fields
3. In the main page, click on the 'Export' tab
4. Make sure the main 'Structure' 'select all' and 'Data' boxes are ticked
5. In the right box, make sure 'Add drop table', 'Add AUTO_INCREMENT value' and 'Enclose table and field names with backquotes' are ticked
6. select the SQL format in the 'export' column'
7. Tick 'Save as file'
8. If you want the backup file compressed, tick either 'zipped' or 'gzipped'
9. Click 'Go'to save your file - the preferred location would be your own PC

**Restoring a backup**

1. In PhpMyAdmin main page - Click on the 'SQL' tab at the top and browse to the location of your backup file.
2. Then select 'Go' from the tab at the bottom right corner of the screen - you may need to empty your existing database before you can restore the backup however normally you don't as the backup will simply overwrite the existing database.

**Back-up / Restore related plugins**

Some plugins that might become handy for not so experienced PhpMyAdmin users:

- [EasyBackup](http://wiki.e107.org/index.php?title=EasyBackup) plugin
- [EasyDBtool](http://wiki.e107.org/index.php?title=EasyDBtool) plugin
- Dbackup plugin